# Socket.io клиент на Android не подключается к серверу Node.js

Tags: android, node.js, socketio-client

Через браузер всё от лично работает, но андроид(эмулятор) при соединение вызывает событие `CONNECT_ERROR`

Код андроид:

```
package com.example.socket;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Main activity";

    public Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        View.OnClickListener Click = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SocketIO socketIO = new SocketIO();
                socketIO.run();
            }
        };

        button.setOnClickListener(Click);
    }



    public class SocketIO implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            final Socket mSocket;

                try {
                    mSocket = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");

                    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                        @Override
                        public void call(Object... args) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "connect success");
                            mSocket.emit("ferret", "tobi");
                            mSocket.disconnect();
                        }

                    }).on("event", new Emitter.Listener() {

                        @Override
                        public void call(Object... args) {

                        }

                    }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                        @Override
                        public void call(Object... args) {

                        }

                    }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Object... args) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error connect");
                        }
                    }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECTING, new Emitter.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Object... args) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Connecting");
                        }
                    }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Object... args) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Connect timeout");
                        }
                    });

                    mSocket.connect();
                } catch (URISyntaxException UTE) {
                    Log.e(TAG, UTE.toString());
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Лог Android studio:

```
D/Main activity: Connecting
E/Main activity: Error connect
```

Код сервера Node:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/page/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('connect user:' + socket.id);
  socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) {
    fn('dsfhdsjfhdkjshfkjdshfkjd');
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    io.emit('user disconnected');
    console.log('disconnect user:' + socket.id);
  });
});
```

Comment: permission есть? версии soket.io на клиенте и сервере?

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` - это localhost, у Вас сервер запущен на самом Андроиде?

Comment: Сервер на win10, permission `INTERNET` и `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`

Comment: На проблемном устройстве/эмуляторе выше 23 версии апи может быть?

Comment: эмулятор API 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost на эмуляторе андроида - 10.0.2.2